# MySQL query with cumulative sum partitioned by product skips dates where there are no values

Tags: sql, mysql

I have been stuck with the following problem:

We have a table called "movimientos_stock" that´s over 12 million rows long. It contains every single in and out from every product from our WMS since the very beggining. This means that if we do a simple query like this one, we obtain the current stock:

```
SELECT
    ms.codigo_art,
    SUM(ms.cantidad) AS stock
FROM movimientos_stock AS ms
GROUP BY ms.codigo_art;
```

codigo_art being the product ID

Now we need a query that returns the stock from each product for each day. With some time and some ChatGPT I have this query that works:

```
SELECT
    ms.fecha,
    ms.codigo,
    SUM(ms.cantidad) OVER(PARTITION BY ms.codigo ORDER BY ms.fecha) as Stock
FROM 
    (SELECT DATE(ms1.fecha) AS fecha, ms1.codigo_art as codigo, sum(ms1.cantidad) as cantidad
    FROM movimientos_stock AS ms1
    GROUP BY 1,2) AS ms
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

fecha being the datetime column

The problem with this query is that if in any given date, there is no movement from a product, it won´t have a line saying that the stock that day stayed the same.
I will demonstrate with a short example of a single product:

| fecha | codigo_art | cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-03 11:12:52 | ALCA01 | 150 |
| 2020-10-04 15:02:12 | ALCA01 | -15 |
| 2020-10-05 07:25:01 | ALCA01 | -25 |
| 2020-10-07 19:47:49 | ALCA01 | -10 |

The desired output of the query is:

| fecha | codigo_art | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-03 | ALCA01 | 150 |
| 2020-10-04 | ALCA01 | 135 |
| 2020-10-05 | ALCA01 | 110 |
| *2020-10-06* | *ALCA01* | *110* |
| 2020-10-07 | ALCA01 | 100 |

But instead I get:

| fecha | codigo_art | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-03 | ALCA01 | 150 |
| 2020-10-04 | ALCA01 | 135 |
| 2020-10-05 | ALCA01 | 110 |
| 2020-10-07 | ALCA01 | 100 |

I understand why it works like this, and it makes sense. The problem is that any variation I try to do to this query just won't work.

The one variation that should work on paper is to first do a crossjoin between distinct fecha and distinct codigo_art. Then, left join it to this:

```
(SELECT DATE(ms1.fecha) AS fecha, ms1.codigo_art as codigo, sum(ms1.cantidad) as cantidad
    FROM movimientos_stock AS ms1
    GROUP BY 1,2) AS ms
```

However, our database in google cloud cannot handle this addition to the query. The CPU usage of our Google Cloud server shoots to 100% for the rest of the day trying to resolve the query even after stopping it just because it´s that huge. Considering our heaviest queries barely scratch 30% usage, I have to believe there is a better way to do this, and it´s not a CPU capacity problem.

Any new ideas would be very welcomed!

Comment: This is where having a calendar table would be very useful. The alternative would be to generate a series of dates between your earliest and latest dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte` to create a range of dates for each `codigo_art` group that the product stock can be joined onto:

```
with recursive cte as (
   select m.codigo_art, min(date(m.fecha)) start, max(date(m.fecha)) end 
   from movimientos_stock m group by m.codigo_art
   union all
   select c.codigo_art, c.start + interval 1 day, c.end from cte c where c.start < c.end
)
select c.codigo_art, c.start, sum(coalesce(m.cantidad, 0)) 
from cte c left join movimientos_stock m on m.codigo_art = c.codigo_art and date(m.fecha) <= c.start
group by c.codigo_art, c.start
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cc0Dg6Sa)